# Type hint for a factory classmethod of an abstract base class in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, generics, abstract-class, mypy, python-typing

I have two abstract classes, `AbstractA` and `AbstractB`. `AbstractB` is generic and its type parameter is bound to `AbstractA`. `AbstractB` further has a factory classmethod that returns an instance of one of its subclasses--which one is determined from some input parameter. See below for a minimal example. Note that, after trial and error, I found that I need to add a type hint for `B_type` in `AbstractB.factory()`.

#### Minimal example

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from abc import ABC
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Type, Any


class AbstractA(ABC):
    pass


class ConcreteA1(AbstractA):
    pass


class ConcreteA2(AbstractA):
    pass


ATypeT = TypeVar("ATypeT", bound=AbstractA)


class AbstractB(ABC, Generic[ATypeT]):

    @classmethod
    def factory(cls, typeB_selector: int) -> AbstractB[Any]: # which type hint here?

        B_type: Type[AbstractB[Any]] # which type hint here?
        if typeB_selector == 1:
            B_type= ConcreteB1
        elif typeB_selector == 2:
            B_type= ConcreteB2

        return B_type()


class ConcreteB1(AbstractB[ConcreteA1]):
    pass


class ConcreteB2(AbstractB[ConcreteA2]):
    pass
```

I'm trying to understand what type hints to use for the return value of `AbstractB.factory()` and `B_type`. From my (admittedly limited) understanding of generics, I believe the appropriate type should be `AbstractB[AbstractA]`. However, with `strict=true`, mypy gives errors for the two `B_type=...` lines; e.g. for the first one:

`Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "type[ConcreteB1]", variable has type "type[AbstractB[AbstractA]]")`.

The only way I can avoid errors is by using `AbstractB[Any]`, as in the example. However, this feels wrong to me, since we know that the type parameter is bound to `AbstractA`. I also tried `AbstractB[ATypeT]`, but that seems wrong as well, and also results in mypy errors.

#### Questions

- Is my assumption that the correct type hint should be `AbstractB[AbstractA]` correct, or am I misunderstanding things?
- Am I doing something weird here? According to my understanding of the factory pattern this seems like a valid approach.

#### Notes

- My actual code properly handles the case when `factory()` is called on one of the subclasses (`ConcreteB1`, `ConcreteB2`).
- There are several similar questions on SO (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46007544/python-3-type-hint-for-a-factory-method-on-a-base-class-returning-a-child-class), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62456303/type-annotations-for-factory-method)), but I believe my case is different because (when `factory()` is called on `AbstractB`) there's no way of telling the type checker which subclass will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things going on here - first of all some general practices:

### Abstract classes should not reference their dependants

To answer your question, yes some of what you're doing here is strange, but the strangest part is that the method on `AbstractB` references it's dependants `ConcreteB1` and `ConcreteB2`. An abstract class should represent common behaviour of the children classes - by trying to reference the two concrete classes it's no longer common behaviour really, and somehow requires knowledge of things it will be used for. Hope that makes sense.

### A solution

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from abc import ABC
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

class AbstractA(ABC):
    pass

class ConcreteA1(AbstractA):
    pass

class ConcreteA2(AbstractA):
    pass


ATypeT = TypeVar("ATypeT", bound=AbstractA)


class AbstractB(ABC, Generic[ATypeT]):
    pass


class ConcreteB1(AbstractB[ConcreteA1]):
    pass

class ConcreteB2(AbstractB[ConcreteA2]):
    pass


def factory(typeB_selector: int) -> ConcreteB1 | ConcreteB2:
    B_type: type[ConcreteB1] | type[ConcreteB2]
    if typeB_selector == 1:
        B_type= ConcreteB1
    elif typeB_selector == 2:
        B_type= ConcreteB2
    else:
        assert False
    return B_type()
```

Now factory only references the inherited classes. You might be thinking, well wait a minute, I wanted it to return the abstract version. Really though, by having the if statement map `int` to class, a union is actually *more* descriptive of the possible outcomes. In fact you could go one step further and do this:

```py
@overload
def factory(typeB_selector: Literal[1]) -> ConcreteB1:
    ...
@overload
def factory(typeB_selector: Literal[2]) -> ConcreteB2:
    ...

def factory(typeB_selector: Literal[1,2]) -> ConcreteB1 | ConcreteB2:
    match typeB_selector:
        case 1:
            return ConcreteB1()
        case 2:
            return ConcreteB2()
```

Now it's clear what maps to what, and we also get the specific type depending on the number entered.

### A note about abstract factories

You can make abstract classmethods that work as factories, but they can't use classes that inherit from them e.g.:

```py
    @classmethod
    def factory(cls) -> Self:
        return cls()
```

The above would be fine, as it only references `cls`.

Comment: Thanks! I see your point regarding base classes referencing their subclasses and, in general, I agree. However, in my actual code the subclasses are not explicitly referenced. Each subclass  of `AbstractB` has a class attribute (let's say `some_var`) whose value is used to select the appropriate subclass. In `factory()`, I loop over the subclasses using `cls.__subclasses__()` until the one is found for which the value of `some_var` matches `typeB_selector`. This way, the base class needs no changes if a subclass is added. Note that this means that your `@overload` approach would not work here.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense - could you update the example to match the actual code? From your description there may actually be a type that works (potentially with use of Self) but would need to see the behaviour with cls.__subclasses__() - cheers!